# Deleting previous node in singly linked list if pointer to only that given current node is given

Tags: list, linked-list

I have to delete the previous node. I searched web but couldnt find the exact sol cuz the list given is singly list and we are not given any other pointer except the current one. How to do this?
The list is neither circular nor doubly linked.

Comment: What if there are two previous nodes? In a singly linked list, a node can have more than one previous.

Comment: @Raymond Chen How two previous nodes?

Comment: Suppose you have three nodes. A.next = C. B.next = C. You are given C. What is its previous node?

Comment: How can A and B both point to C in a singly linked list?

Comment: The list is in the way A->B->C, and u are given B and u have to delete A.

Comment: But how do you know that there isn't a `D` somewhere that also points to `B`? How will you know whether `A` or `D` is the one to delete?

Comment: in a singly linked list one node points to another and hence A points to B and B to C, how D comes in between, m not getting that.

Comment: D is not in between. It is another node which points to B. Look at it this way: Suppose there are two nodes X and Y, and both point to Z. Which one is the parent of Z?

Comment: How can this be implemented in relation to my doubt??

Comment: You need some way to prove that no such D exists. Since you didn't give a programming language, it is not clear whether such a proof is possible. (For example, no such proof is possible in assembly language.)

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the code, but you can get the gist of the algorithm.  Note that this is assuming that this is a single-linked list structure

1. Mark the current node of the list
2. Iterate through the list with a loop.  For each node,

   1. Check if the next node pointer is the marked node.

      1. If it is, execute the delete operation for a singly linked list.
      2. If it is not a marked node, move to the next node.

Comment: This assumes the list is circular.

Comment: Exactly, either we need a circular list or a doubly linked list, but its strictly given we have a singly linked list and only a current node pointer.

Comment: @Jason You code assumes that you have a pointer to the start of the list

Comment: @user3004790, then you should modify the question to include these details.

Comment: @RaymondChen, correct, but given the sparsity of details provided by the OP, I decided to go with a simple algorithm.  If necessary, OP can implement a variant of this algorithm should the list be a non-circular structure.